# Typescript: Get a unique list of values using a dynamic field name

Tags: typescript

There is a class. Let's say:

```
class Foo {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}
```

and a function to get the new Set of unique values.

```
getUniqueSet<T, K extends keyof T>(arr: T[], key: K): Set<T[K]> {
  return new Set<T[K]>(arr.map(item => item[key]))
}
```

How can I use the function without the following TS error:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof Foo'.

when I am working with it as following:

```
const fieldNames: string[] = ['a', 'b'];
const foos: Foo[] = [{a: '1', b: 1}, {a: '2', b: 2}];

fieldNames.forEach((fieldName: string) => {
  // Simplified code
  let uniqueSet = this.getUniqueSet(this.foos, fieldName);
});
```

My goal is to pass a collection of field names (`fieldNames`) and get unique values for each field based on the `foos` data collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: you can define `fieldNames` as an array of keys of Foo `(keyof Foo)[]`.
Not all strings are a key of Foo so the compiler gives an error.

```
const fieldNames: (keyof Foo)[] = ['a', 'b'];
const foos: Foo[] = [{ a: '1', b: 1 }, { a: '2', b: 2 }];

fieldNames.forEach((fieldName) => {
  // Simplified code
  let uniqueSet = getUniqueSet(foos, fieldName);
});
```